Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage') Google gapi.auth2
Everything is working perfectly until this page loads
 
The pop-up gets blank and the following error is displayed on the console: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'postMessage')
This only happens to some inactive accounts, is there a recommended way to handle this or is this a error in code?
I'm using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google in a create-react-app (SPA)
The user should be logged in or the pop-up should show the next page
